# How to prove that $\phi=f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$ is a bijection without using $h$?

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, diffeomorphism

If $f:\mathbb{R}^3\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by $f(a,b,c)=e^{a^2}+e^{b^2}+e^{c^2}$ defining $h:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ by $h(t)= f(ta, tb, tc)$, we have that $h'(t)>0$ give us all conditions to define a bijection (diffeomorphism) $\phi=f:S\rightarrow \mathbb{S}^2$. Would someone explain this bijection please? And also help me to find another way to prove this? ($S=\{(a, b, c)\in \mathbb{R}^3: f(a, b, c)=a\}\; \text{with}\; a>3$)

Comment: This question is very unfocussed. There are **lots** of steps on this page and I would not wish to guess which of these many steps is dis-satisfactory to you.

Comment: Just that I've asked, this is: how to prove that $\phi=f:S\rightarrow S^2$ is bijective (whithout using  $h$)?

Comment: Because I did not understand how $h$ is proving that $\phi$ is bijective. (I did not see the injective and surjective parts)

Comment: Then you should rewrite your question to state, right at the beginning, exactly what you want. As currently written, we have to scroll through a long attachment, and then we have to figure out that what you are really asking is buried in what looks like a parenthetical comment.

Comment: @LeeMosher I've done as your advice. Would you tell me if it is ok now?

Comment: Quite a coincidence that [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4070029/global-diffeomorphism-between-two-surfaces/4070044?noredirect=1#comment8409325_4070044) showed up yesterday.

Comment: "I need your help in 12 hours." It sure sounds like this is an exam question that you've found in a book. I didn't downvote, but I would normally vote to close.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a slightly confusingly-worded proof, but the essential idea is to show that for every $(x,y,z)\ne 0$, the half line $\{ t(x,y,z) \mid t\ge 0\}$ intersects the surface $S$ at precisely one point. This is what the argument with $h$ shows: since $h(t)$ ranges from 3 to $+\infty$ as $t$ ranges from $0$ to $+\infty$, it must equal $a$ for *at least* one value of $t$. Since $h'(t)>0$, $h$ is monotonically increasing, and so it equals $a$ for *at most* one value of $t$. Therefore $h(t)$ equals $a$ for $precisely$ one value of $t$. For this value $t^*$ of $t$, $t^*(x,y,z)$ is an element of $S$.

Now the half line $\{ t(x,y,z) \mid t\ge 0\}$ also intersects the sphere $\mathbb{S}^2$ at precisely one point (obviously). The mapping $f:S\to \mathbb{S}^2$ given by $f(p) = \frac{p}{|p|}$ maps the point in the half line intersecting $S$ to the point intersecting $\mathbb{S}^2$, and so is injective. It's also surjective - take any $(x,y,z)\in \mathbb{S}^2$ and apply the above argument to find a $t^*(x,y,z)\in S$. Then $f(t^*(x,y,z)) = (x,y,z)$. Therefore $f$ is bijective.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. This solved my doubt related to understand $h$. Congratulations for your gift in have an easy geometric view of these kind of problems. Sure, I will vote your answer! =D

Comment: PS. If you have any idea in how to prove this bijection without defining that $h$, please let me know. Because I tried in another way,but I failed. (Thanks for everything).