# Global diffeomorphism between two surfaces

Tags: geometry, analysis, differential-geometry

I tried to show the function $ f: S_a \to \mathbb{S}^2$, given by

$$ f(p) = \dfrac{p}{|p|}$$

is a global diffeomorphism between $S_a$ and $\mathbb{S}^2$ where

$$S_a = \{(x,y,z) : e^{x^2}+ e^{y^2} + e^{z^2} = a\}$$

and $a>3$ is a real number fixed. I already proved that $f$ is a local diffeomorphism, but I'm not able to show that $f$ is injective to conclude $f$ is a global diffeomorphism.
Someone can help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**: Fix $(x,y,z)\in S^2$. Consider the function $g(t)=e^{(tx)^2}+e^{(ty)^2}+e^{(tz)^2}$. Can you show that $g$ is an increasing function of $t\in (0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes, $g$ is a increasing function of $t\in (0,+\infty)$. But I can't see how this will ensure the injectivity of f

Comment: What does it mean if $f(p)=f(q)$ for $p,q\in S_a$?

Comment: means that p and q are associated with the same unit point in the sphere. The vectors connecting the origin to p and the origin to q are parallel

Comment: In other words, if $f(p)=(x,y,z)$, then $p=t_1(x,y,z)$ and $q=t_2(x,y,z)$.

Comment: Thank you so much.

Comment: You're welcome. People on this site are sick of hearing me say this, but sometimes it helps to think about the problem a bit geometrically :)